# ¿Como puedo localizar un dato especifico dentro de un arreglo de objetos ya pre cargado?

Tags: java

```
Cliente arrCliente[] = new Cliente[10];

//Primer Cliente


objCliente.setCuenta("1");
objCliente.setIdentificacion("1-1371-0735");
objCliente.setNombre("Angelo");
objCliente.setClave(1234);
objCliente.setSaldo(5000);
objCliente.setBloqueado(false);
arrCliente[0] = objCliente;

objCliente.setCuenta("2");
objCliente.setIdentificacion("1-1111-1111");
objCliente.setNombre("Carlos");
objCliente.setClave(1111);
objCliente.setSaldo(3000);
objCliente.setBloqueado(false);
arrCliente[1] = objCliente;
//Aquí estoy ingresando los datos en el arreglo por medio de la propiedad set.
do{
    String Menu = "Menu Principal \n";
    Menu += "1. consulta de saldo \n";
    Menu += "2. Depositos \n";
    Menu += "3. Retiros \n";
    Menu += "4. Salir \n";

    opc =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Menu));

    switch (opc){
        case 1:{
            //Consulta.getSaldo()
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El Saldo actual a la      fecha es de: " + objCliente.ConsultaSaldo(arrCliente));
            }break;
        case 2:{
            int Monto = 0;
            Monto = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el Monto a depositar"));
            if (Monto <= 0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se puede realizar la transaccion, monto invalido.");
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El deposito se ha realizado exitosamente \n su saldo a la fecha es de: " + objCliente.Deposito(arrCliente, Monto));
            }
            }break;
        case 3:{
            int Monto = 0;
            Monto = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el Monto a retirar"));
            if (Monto >= objCliente.getSaldo()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fondos insuficientes.");
            break;
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El retiro se ha realizado exitosamente \n su saldo a la fecha es de: " + objCliente.Retiro(arrCliente, Monto));
            }
            }break;
        case 4:{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hasta pronto.");
            }break;
        default:{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La opcion ingresada no es valida" + " intente una opcion valida.");
            }break;
    }
}while (opc != 4);
```

//Necesito saber como hago para que los métodos específicos para cada opción me devuelvan el valor almacenada en x posición.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero tienes que preguntar que cliente está operando, sinó, es imposible que sepas que posicion del array debes modificar / consultar:

**CODIGO** ojo con los comentarios, es una adaptación para que veas como se hace, pero deberás modificarla

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // simulacion de tu arreglo de clientes
    String[] clientes = { "Angelo" , "Carlos", "Pepa", "Laura" };
    int posicion = 1;

    // construimos el mensaje a mostrar
    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder("Cual es tu numero de cliente?\n");
    for (String cliente : clientes) { // para ti    for (Cliente cliente : arrCliente) {  
        msg.append("\n" + (posicion++) + "-" + cliente); //    para ti       msg.append("\n" + cliente.getNombre()); 
    }

    // adquirimos el numero de cliente 
    // OJO el numero asignado es la posicion en el array + 1!!!!!
    int cliente =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(msg));
    int posicionEnElArray = cliente - 1;

    System.out.println("La posicion del cliente " + clientes[posicionEnElArray] + " en el array es " + posicionEnElArray);
}
```

**SALIDA:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
La posicion del cliente Carlos en el array es 1
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias.